# Modifying the results of a Core Data fetch request before displaying them

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, random, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got an application which pulls back data from a database using Core Data, and displaying it in a custom cell in a `UITableView`, via an `NSFetchedResultsController`. I'd like to randomly insert a different type of custom cell every now and then (say, between every 10 and 20 cells), which will NOT get its data from that same database, and will be a different subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

I'm a little stumped on how I get in the middle of the `NSFetchedResultsController` and the `UITableView` Data Source methods. I have various options which allow the data that's pulled in to be sorted, filtered, etc., so I can't rely on using indexPath or anything like that.

What's the best approach to doing something like this? I know I can access `fetchedObjects` of the `NSFetchedResultsController` – is copying and modifying that the right way forward? Create, say, `fetchedObjectWithInterstitialCells`, and feed all of the Data Source and Delegate methods with the contents of that array?

Is there a better way / are there alternative ways to do it? I'll need to be able to retain the ability to sort / modify / filter the data from the database, while at all times keeping these interstitial cells at that same interval of randomly between every 10 and 20 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider one of the following three operations:

A: Insert objects into the database that are pulled along with the other data, but has properties to differentiate them enough to display the different subclass of the UITableViewCell. Probably the easiest way out, unless you have a very difficult datamodel.

B: If you can group your data from the data store into sections by using the `sectionNameKeyPath`-attribute on the `NSFetchedResultsController`, go for the `NSFetchedResultsController` + `UITableViewDataSource`-approach, and then return `[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] + numberOfInterstitialCells;` inside `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you would then need to override the section-info from the indexpath in order to switch between the right object from FetchedResultscontroller and your interstitial cells. This is probably a cumbersome and difficult way to do it, but if you are on iOS6 using parentContexts, the benefit from having implemented the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` is awesome

C: Fetch the objects with a normal fetchrequest and put them into a mutable array in which you insert your interstitial cells, before you load your view and feed your `UITableViewDataSource` with this array. As easy as option A, but you won't get the benefits of having the NSFetchedResults-Controller.

Comment: I like option A, but I think it's gonna take quite a lot of trial & error to get the balance. For example, if I had 5,000 of my regular objects, that'd mean I'd need approximately 333 of the interstitials if I wanted one interstitial for every fifteen regular cells.

This also means that I might have issues when sorting, i.e. if I choose to sort all 5,000 results randomly, I may end up with more than one of the interstitials in a row, which I wouldn't want. Can you give me any ideas on how I might overcome these sorts of things? Advice so far has been perfect, really grateful! :)

Comment: Just a thought.... Instead of inserting objects in your array, why not adjust the cell height right before you are going to insert the object to contain both your data and the interstitial? Then your datamodel will be mirroring your actual data, and you won't have to think of any inserts or sortingproblems? There is nothing wrong in a good illusion, also, returning different height for different rows is a rather simple trick....

Comment: That sounds like an excellent idea. Could I set it up so that tapping the interstitial triggered something different to tapping the cell itself? I suppose I could just overlay two invisible views over each part of the cell, and put tap recognizers on them?

Comment: A UIButton, or a UIControl-subclassed element as the "interstitial" below the cellview would probably solve your problem.